# Isolating the desired event in EEG signals

Tags: experimental-psychology, eeg

When we took an EEG data from subjects, does the subject have to be in  "neutral state" i.e there is no anger, no sadness,   no happiness ...etc. and they also in situation that they  neither do any logical operations nor any concerns in their life events?

Often when I read in the literature, they assume that the subject is in this situation above! For example if someone want to elicit the emotion state on the subject from an EEG signal , it's feature extraction process depends on the variance of the signal, and it's assumed that all variance in the EEG is for only the emotions. The brain process a lot of processes, and the signal will contains Emotion , logical operation ,  the usually processes to organize human functions ... etc .

So what is the rational judgment on this experiment? Assuming that the subject so clever and operated with experimenter, how much will he really control on his mind behavior?

In short : **how can we depend on parameters (i.e variance) for evidence when this parameter does not only depend on the behavior that we want to make a decision with?**

I know that when we deal with event related potentials (ERPs) , we  make the parameters  highly dependent on that event , but this is does not apply on inner-voice research.

Comment: Interesting question! What do you mean by "I know that we deal with event related potentials (ERD)"? (it should be ERP btw). Is your question about ERPs or about EEG signals? This is important when answering this question, as you correctly identify in the question. If your question is about "innner-voice research" you should specify this. The question is unclear and too broad as of now. Some background info would help.

Comment: @ChrisStronks , I means that when we do ERP Experiments we approximately isolate the parameters to be nearly close to be completely dependent to the event that experiments focus on . which is a part of the answer of my question. So my question is about "inner-voice research".

Comment: @ChrisStronks I thought that ERPs is a subset of EEG researches , from your words it's seems that they independent on each other :)

Comment: You are totally right, but I did not understand your question was on ERPs. Personally, I still don't understand your question, but that may be me. So you measure ERPs? Then I would like to know what is the stimulus used to evoke the ERP? And what exactly is the role of emotional state here?

Comment: @ChrisStronks , I apologize for my poor English language, which is leading you to misunderstand my ideas  , Anyway my question is "how to Isolate  the desired event in the inner-voice experiment"

Comment: @Learner can you give us citations for inner-voice research you're following up on?  That would help give us an idea of the paradigm.